# How to call an div's attributes value using a function if there are many div's with the same function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code:

```
function openCanviewer() {
    var cid = $(this).data('cid');
    alert(cid);
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div onclick="openCanviewer();" data-cid="ID OF CAN FROM DATABASE"></div>
```

My problem is that when I click the element with the onclick function, which I have many of because they get inserted from the database, the alert is just showing "undefined" instead of the contents of the data-cid attribute. Does someone have any idea what I have done wrong, or what I am missing here?

Comment: aww. Id should be unique in a page. Change the title

Comment: @SagarV is correct. IDs must be unique.

Comment: Yeah I've changed the title, I am not even using any ID's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general you shouldn't use inline events like `onclick="openCanviewer();"`, you should always keep js, css and html separate.

For your problem you could use delegate event listening:

```
function openCanviewer() {
  var cid = $(this).data('cid');
  alert(cid);
}

$(document).on('click', '[data-cid]', openCanviewer)
```

Comment: You should also use `dataset` to access data- attributes!

Comment: @niceass How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

To capture the exact element, pass `this` from the element's click event handler

```
function openCanviewer(element) {
    var cid = $(element).data('cid');
    alert(cid);
}


<div onclick="openCanviewer(this);" data-cid="ID OF CAN FROM DATABASE"></div>
                       ^^^ you have a typo here
```

Snippet

```js
function openCanviewer(element) {
  var cid = $(element).data('cid');
  alert(cid);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div onclick="openCanviewer(this);" data-cid="ID OF CAN FROM DATABASE">Click</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, that Typo isn't in the actual code of my project. I've just set it up cleaner, because it contained many classes and more attributes.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#mi').click(function() {
  var cid = $(this).data('cid');
  alert(cid);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mi" data-cid="ID OF CAN FROM DATABASE">hello</div>
```